После установки расширения MobileFrontend вики на движке MediaWiki перестала работать
Ошибка возникла сразу после установки расширения.
Возможно исправить это? Или нужно обращаться к разработчикам расширения? Вроде версия mediawiki и расширения совпадают.
Устанавливал в папку extensions/
MediaWiki internal error.

Original exception: [ZiU6YCSiHPnVKmlcnFomxgAAABM] /index.php/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F:%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F TypeError: MobileFrontend\Features\Feature::__construct(): Argument #3 ($options) must be of type array, bool given, called in /home/vol10_1/infinityfree.com/if0_36402848/htdocs/extensions/MobileFrontend/includes/ServiceWiring.php on line 38
Backtrace:
from /home/vol10_1/infinityfree.com/if0_36402848/htdocs/extensions/MobileFrontend/includes/Features/Feature.php(30)
#0 /home/vol10_1/infinityfree.com/if0_36402848/htdocs/extensions/MobileFrontend/includes/ServiceWiring.php(38): MobileFrontend\Features\Feature->__construct(string, string, boolean)
#1 /home/vol10_1/infinityfree.com/if0_36402848/htdocs/vendor/wikimedia/services/src/ServiceContainer.php(445): Wikimedia\Services\ServiceContainer::{closure}(MediaWiki\MediaWikiServices)
#2 /home/vol10_1/infinityfree.com/if0_36402848/htdocs/vendor/wikimedia/services/src/ServiceContainer.php(411): Wikimedia\Services\ServiceContainer->createService(string)
#3 /home/vol10_1/infinityfree.com/if0_36402848/htdocs/includes/MediaWikiServices.php(301): Wikimedia\Services\ServiceContainer->getService(string)
#4 /home/vol10_1/infinityfree.com/if0_36402848/htdocs/extensions/MobileFrontend/includes/MobileFrontendHooks.php(636): MediaWiki\MediaWikiServices->getService(string)
#5 /home/vol10_1/infinityfree.com/if0_36402848/htdocs/includes/HookContainer/HookContainer.php(338): MobileFrontendHooks::onSpecialPageInitList(array)
#6 /home/vol10_1/infinityfree.com/if0_36402848/htdocs/includes/HookContainer/HookContainer.php(137): MediaWiki\HookContainer\HookContainer->callLegacyHook(string, array, array, array)
#7 /home/vol10_1/infinityfree.com/if0_36402848/htdocs/includes/HookContainer/HookRunner.php(3692): MediaWiki\HookContainer\HookContainer->run(string, array)
#8 /home/vol10_1/infinityfree.com/if0_36402848/htdocs/includes/specialpage/SpecialPageFactory.php(1165): MediaWiki\HookContainer\HookRunner->onSpecialPage_initList(array)
#9 /home/vol10_1/infinityfree.com/if0_36402848/htdocs/includes/specialpage/SpecialPageFactory.php(1180): MediaWiki\SpecialPage\SpecialPageFactory->getPageList()
#10 /home/vol10_1/infinityfree.com/if0_36402848/htdocs/includes/specialpage/SpecialPageFactory.php(1238): MediaWiki\SpecialPage\SpecialPageFactory->getAliasList()
#11 /home/vol10_1/infinityfree.com/if0_36402848/htdocs/includes/Title.php(1287): MediaWiki\SpecialPage\SpecialPageFactory->resolveAlias(string)
#12 /home/vol10_1/infinityfree.com/if0_36402848/htdocs/includes/MediaWiki.php(212): Title->isSpecial(string)
#13 /home/vol10_1/infinityfree.com/if0_36402848/htdocs/includes/MediaWiki.php(904): MediaWiki->performRequest()
#14 /home/vol10_1/infinityfree.com/if0_36402848/htdocs/includes/MediaWiki.php(562): MediaWiki->main()
#15 /home/vol10_1/infinityfree.com/if0_36402848/htdocs/index.php(50): MediaWiki->run()
#16 /home/vol10_1/infinityfree.com/if0_36402848/htdocs/index.php(46): wfIndexMain()
#17 {main}

Exception caught inside exception handler: [ZiU6YCSiHPnVKmlcnFomxgAAABM] /index.php/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F:%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F TypeError: MobileFrontend\Features\Feature::__construct(): Argument #3 ($options) must be of type array, bool given, called in /home/vol10_1/infinityfree.com/if0_36402848/htdocs/extensions/MobileFrontend/includes/ServiceWiring.php on line 38
Backtrace:
from /home/vol10_1/infinityfree.com/if0_36402848/htdocs/extensions/MobileFrontend/includes/Features/Feature.php(30)
#0 /home/vol10_1/infinityfree.com/if0_36402848/htdocs/extensions/MobileFrontend/includes/ServiceWiring.php(38): MobileFrontend\Features\Feature->__construct(string, string, boolean)
#1 /home/vol10_1/infinityfree.com/if0_36402848/htdocs/vendor/wikimedia/services/src/ServiceContainer.php(445): Wikimedia\Services\ServiceContainer::{closure}(MediaWiki\MediaWikiServices)
#2 /home/vol10_1/infinityfree.com/if0_36402848/htdocs/vendor/wikimedia/services/src/ServiceContainer.php(411): Wikimedia\Services\ServiceContainer->createService(string)
#3 /home/vol10_1/infinityfree.com/if0_36402848/htdocs/includes/MediaWikiServices.php(301): Wikimedia\Services\ServiceContainer->getService(string)
#4 /home/vol10_1/infinityfree.com/if0_36402848/htdocs/extensions/MobileFrontend/includes/MobileFrontendHooks.php(1123): MediaWiki\MediaWikiServices->getService(string)
#5 /home/vol10_1/infinityfree.com/if0_36402848/htdocs/includes/HookContainer/HookContainer.php(338): MobileFrontendHooks::onMakeGlobalVariablesScript(array, OutputPage)
#6 /home/vol10_1/infinityfree.com/if0_36402848/htdocs/includes/HookContainer/HookContainer.php(137): MediaWiki\HookContainer\HookContainer->callLegacyHook(string, array, array, array)
#7 /home/vol10_1/infinityfree.com/if0_36402848/htdocs/includes/HookContainer/HookRunner.php(2490): MediaWiki\HookContainer\HookContainer->run(string, array, array)
#8 /home/vol10_1/infinityfree.com/if0_36402848/htdocs/includes/OutputPage.php(3678): MediaWiki\HookContainer\HookRunner->onMakeGlobalVariablesScript(array, OutputPage)
#9 /home/vol10_1/infinityfree.com/if0_36402848/htdocs/includes/OutputPage.php(3324): OutputPage->getJSVars()
#10 /home/vol10_1/infinityfree.com/if0_36402848/htdocs/includes/OutputPage.php(3346): OutputPage->getRlClient()
#11 /home/vol10_1/infinityfree.com/if0_36402848/htdocs/includes/skins/SkinMustache.php(63): OutputPage->headElement(MediaWiki\Skins\Vector\SkinVector22)
#12 /home/vol10_1/infinityfree.com/if0_36402848/htdocs/includes/skins/SkinTemplate.php(177): SkinMustache->generateHTML()
#13 /home/vol10_1/infinityfree.com/if0_36402848/htdocs/includes/OutputPage.php(2876): SkinTemplate->outputPage()
#14 /home/vol10_1/infinityfree.com/if0_36402848/htdocs/includes/exception/MWExceptionRenderer.php(183): OutputPage->output()
#15 /home/vol10_1/infinityfree.com/if0_36402848/htdocs/includes/exception/MWExceptionRenderer.php(102): MWExceptionRenderer::reportHTML(TypeError)
#16 /home/vol10_1/infinityfree.com/if0_36402848/htdocs/includes/exception/MWExceptionHandler.php(131): MWExceptionRenderer::output(TypeError, integer)
#17 /home/vol10_1/infinityfree.com/if0_36402848/htdocs/includes/exception/MWExceptionHandler.php(248): MWExceptionHandler::report(TypeError)
#18 /home/vol10_1/infinityfree.com/if0_36402848/htdocs/includes/MediaWiki.php(584): MWExceptionHandler::handleException(TypeError, string)
#19 /home/vol10_1/infinityfree.com/if0_36402848/htdocs/index.php(50): MediaWiki->run()
#20 /home/vol10_1/infinityfree.com/if0_36402848/htdocs/index.php(46): wfIndexMain()
#21 {main}

